# Git push Error "unable to migrate objects to permanent storage"

Tags: git, hash

Today i had the following issue with my private git:

- 1. I wanted to push the same way as alway
- 2. I got the error error: *unable to write sha1 filename  ... git "unable - to migrate objects to permanent storage"*
- 3. I checked if my storage have enough space ... it had
- 4. I pushed file by file to get get the buggy one
- 5. I found a file with a special content, a single word, that caused that error
- 6. I created a new file with a different name but the same content -> error happend again
- 7. I changed the content of the "buggy" file and I was able to push it

Question: What happend? Got I a Hash collisition?

Comment: *What happend? Got I a Hash collisition?* Not enough information in your question to answer, but it's extremely unlikely (not impossible, just impressively unlikely).

Comment: What information is needed? I use tortoisegit at win 10. commit works fine. This was the only file i cannot push to the git server on my local file station.

Comment: Someone would need access to the server itself (to install a debug version of Git), or both repositories if we don't have access to the server.

Comment: that is something I can't provide ;-) but thank you for the comment